# LOF and LOT customization in memoir

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, memoir, tocloft

I am attempting to add LOF and LOT to my current document using the memoir class. When I try to remove the spacing above the LOF and LOT titles, I get the "Undefined control sequence. \setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{0pt}" error. I have commented out the lines

```
\setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{0pt}
```

and

```
\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{0pt}
```

A skeleton version of my document is shown below

### Working Example

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\DisemulatePackage{setspace}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% toc depth
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
\settocdepth{section}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}

% name toc
\renewcommand{\contentsname}
{\centerline{\normalsize{\normalfont{\MakeUppercase{Table of Contents}}}}}

% set chapter scshape
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\scshape}

% add dots to the TOC Chapters
\renewcommand{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}

% indent in TOC
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0in}{0.5in}
\cftsetindents{section}{0.5in}{0.5in}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{1.0in}{0.5in}

% add period after number in TOC
%memoir
\renewcommand{\cftchapteraftersnum}{.}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}

% remove and space before after toc title
\renewcommand{\aftertoctitle}{\vspace{1em}}
\renewcommand{\tocheadstart}{}

\addtocontents{toc}{\noindent\textbf{Chapter}\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}

\tableofcontents*
\newpage

% LIST OF TABLES
\renewcommand{\listtablename}
{\centerline{\normalsize{\normalfont{\MakeUppercase{List of Tables}}}}}

\addtocontents{lot}{\noindent\textbf{Table}~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}

%\setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{0pt}
\listoftables*
\newpage

% LIST OF FIGURES
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}
{\centerline{\normalsize{\normalfont{\MakeUppercase{List of Figures}}}}}

\addtocontents{lof}{\noindent\textbf{Figure}~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}

%\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{0pt}
\listoffigures*
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\doublespacing

\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext
\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{This is a table}    
\end{table}
\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{This is another table}    
\end{table}

\section{Intro Sample Section}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{This is a figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{This is another figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here is what the page looks like with the line uncommented:

### Screenshot

[image: screenshot]

### Questions:

- How do I remove/adjust the space above and below the LOF and LOT headings? I was able to do it for TOC with just two lines.
- In case of TOC/LOF/LOT spanning multiple pages, is there a way to repeat the TOC/LOF/LOT headings and a line such as "Figure... Page" below the heading and such on every following page.

### Solution:

- Remove space before headings: `\renewcommand*{\Xheadstart}{\vspace{0em}}`. Adjust space after headings: `\renewcommand{\afterXtitle}{\vspace{1em}}`. Where `X` is `toc`,`lot`,`lof`
- Having a clean and uniform continuous headings is somewhat difficult from my understanding. The closest I could get was by adding "Figure... Page" to the right and left sections of the headers. Not the prettiest but is better than nothing. More information on this in Page 365 (Section 21.2.3) of the `memoir` manual.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please try to reduce your example to a minimum working one (anyway). In addition, you are asking a bunch of questions actually

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I thought it was minimal. All the custom formatting I have will effect the look-and-feel I want to achieve. What do you suggest I remove to make the example better?

Comment: [Memoir manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf), section 21.2.4 "The ToC and friends", `\renewcommand*{\lotheadstart}{\vspace*{-\topfiddle}}` was used to move the heading up to the top of the page.

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm. The custom packages being built into memoir seems to be reason none of the default package commands work. `\Xheadstart` where X is toc,lof,lot. Thanks.

Comment: Memoir is its own world, sometimes. But once a document gets to a certain level of complexity, the number of packages required and code you'd have to write runs longer than the memoir equivalent. I think I reduced my university's thesis template by around 50% by rewriting it in memoir.

Comment: [Table of Contents (Continued) heading](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/227423)

Comment: You already got the solution to the first problem, can you get the above informationi and write up a self answer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the op found an answer and added it to the end of the question, then disappeared from the site.

Answer (score 2):

- Remove space before headings: `\renewcommand*{\Xheadstart}{\vspace{0em}}`. Adjust space after headings: `\renewcommand{\afterXtitle}{\vspace{1em}}`. Where `X` is `toc`,`lot`,`lof`
- Having a clean and uniform continuous headings is somewhat difficult from my understanding. The closest I could get was by adding "Figure... Page" to the right and left sections of the headers. Not the prettiest but is better than nothing. More information on this in Page 365 (Section 21.2.3) of the `memoir` manual.