# Table of Contents (Continued) heading

Tags: table-of-contents

The solution here [How to add some text to every page of the TOC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23923/changing-the-table-of-contents) for getting a "Table of Contents (Continued)" heading in the text of the second page of the table of contents works very well and is the best solution I have found after quite a lot of research, but are there any ideas on how I get this on to the third page of the table of contents?

Comment: Hi and welcome, this is the manual approach, so exactly the same way a bit later. Please see also http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=252#p87147 and [Add 'Page' above page numbers in Table of Contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8296)

Comment: Thanks very much @Johannes_B, works great. I placed the `\addtocontents{toc}{\contheading}` in the main body of the text between the two sections where the page break of the toc occurs.

Comment: As the linked page mentions that this can be repeated, i suggest to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: It doesn't say\show how to repeat it, and in this way is not an answer to the question. I had to go to the link provided by Johannes_B http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=252#p87147 to understand how to repeat. Should I or someone else edit it to show this?

Comment: @Johannes_B Hopefully I didn't come off as rude in the last comment. Reads that way but not intended at all.

Comment: @Geoarch I edited the answer by stefan a little bit. Can you say that you would have known what to do? If not, i can add some more explanations or write up an answer here. With gaining experience, you will know how to do it, the problem is with that, that it is hard to see the side of a beginner for whom it is not obvious.

Comment: @Geoarch The problem with written communication over the internet: you cannot tell any emotions. Some people feel offended by a very short and *cold* message like »This is rubbish, kick it out« but when you are in a hurry and want to help, this is totally fine (imho). Who has the time to write »hi, what you have done there is obsolete for over 20 years but still appears on google searches. Remove it and it should work. Best regards« To sum it up, didn't read rude at all. ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes I think that with your edits I would have been able to figure out the solution. Glad that you understood where I was coming from in my comment. I know that the goal is to get to the facts here, which is something I struggle with often. Thanks for all of your help.